# Issue with docker permissions

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-volume

I just learning about docker Volumes.
I have this code aside Node.js project.
this is my Docker file:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

VOLUME [ "./app.feedback" ]

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

and this is my command

```
docker run -d -p 3000:80 --rm --name feedback-app -v feedback:/app/feedback -v "C:\Users\amit\personal\data-volumes-01-starting-setup:/app"  -v /app/node_modules feedback-node:volumes
```

and this is the error

```
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:75: mounting "/var/lib/docker/volumes/ebfb2e17b5bf6768527c205789667de5ca31b29b9a9603297b7fbc2881c95701/_data" to rootfs at "/app/node_modules" caused: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/87136c8400ec6a42517fb51eb41084c6a6e5825f877addb7dea71af167a7a43d/merged/app/node_modules: permission denied: unknown.
PS C:\Users\amit\personal\data-volumes-01-starting-setup>
```

Comment: Your application and its `node_modules` directory are already built into the image; you do not need `docker run -v` options for those directories.  If `/app/fedback` or `/app/app.feedback` needs to store persistent data across container invocations then that specific option makes sense, but you do not need the Dockerfile `VOLUME` declaration.

Comment: I know I don't need the VOLUME declaration.
I actually following internet course on Docker.

Comment: If you remove all of the `-v` options except `-v feedback:/app/feedback`, does it work better?  (I could see mounting a Docker anonymous volume over a Windows bind mount having trouble.)

Answer (score 0):

Use this **base image** instead:

```js
FROM node:lts-alpine
```

Comment: this isn't solved the problem, same error